Basement window leaking around steel casing
My basement window is leaking around the steel casing that sits on the concrete. The window has been replaced and I’m wondering if the casing and window should have been replaced with a bigger window? If not how do I stop the leaking?


This leak. Where is it appearing on the casing? Is the casing rusted through at the bottom?

I think we need a few closeups.
